# Excel 2013 ignoring line transparency for shape

Tags: excel, transparency, shapes, excel-2013, vba

I am building an application in Excel 2013 that draws graphs and then fills the area under the graph using AddPolyline to create shapes. I then color these shapes using RGB **and Transparency**.

Everything is working fine except that Excel completely ignores the Transparency factor for the Line.

```
myShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(R, G, B)
myShape.Fill.Transparency = T

myShape.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(R, G, B)
myShape.Line.Transparency = T
```

Currently I am having to reside to a backup solution which is to just make the line invisible using:

```
myShape.Line.Visible = False
```

However, this leaves little white markers between my shapes that should otherwise be perfectly aligned.

I have tried things like making the line weight small etc.

Can anyone else confirm this behavior as a bug, or point out what I am doing wrong?

Edit:

Attached a screenshot of the issue.

[image: white borders]

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload a picture with the whitemarkers?

Comment: @bonCodigo I edited the OP with a screenshot. This is after I changed "False" to "msoFalse" which had no impact.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure what you are dealing is not a border but a true [line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193775.aspx). Check on [LineFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194214.aspx) properties.

> For a line, the LineFormat object contains formatting information for the line itself; for a shape with a border, this object contains formatting information for the shape's border.

Try `myShape.Line.Visible = msoFalse`

Not to forget that `Transparency` property `LineFormat` object infact refers to the specified `fill` of the shape.

You may also record a macro while following [this tutorial to check the exact properties of polylines.](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Add-a-shape-fill-or-effect-28d8dc7f-5bc2-4f83-bb07-615f84ca77d1?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA)

On another note, why don't you make the line colour as same as shape colour? In that case, there wouldn't be a different between the line and the shape. However this clearly depends on your usage and intention.

Few references to consider regarding [buggy & awakward shape, line properties.](https://superuser.com/q/853179)

Comment: I do want to make the line color exactly the same as the fill color, but considering Excel is ignoring the transparency factor the color comes out very different.

Comment: Also,  changing the myshape.line.forecolor definitely changes the border of the shape, so I do think this is the right parameter to mess with.

Comment: It's evident that you have a border component here. If you noticed the first link : `line` provided in my answer, the VBA example shows clearly, the line colour, style is achieved through `forecolor` property.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. As I mentioned in the OP: I can set the myShape.Line.Transparency factor but Excel ignores it. Are you saying there is a myShape.Line.ForeColor.Transparency property? Setting the line color exactly the same as the fill color is indeed the whole point of my post.

Comment: `.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) ` or whatever RGB fill colour that you used.